# I want to know how to change a number into the corresponding value as text in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a django project and I have a method that return the salary for the employee, the salary is being returned as a number like 5432 and i want to display it as five thousand four hundred and thirty two. I tried to use humanize but it works for only small digits any clue?? 
regards,

Answer (score 0):

Here's some Javascript that you can use, courtesy of [About.com's Banking page](http://banking.about.com/library/bl_write_out_numbers.htm):

```
<script  type="text/javascript">

// Convert numbers to words
// copyright 25th July 2006, by Stephen Chapman http://javascript.about.com
// permission to use this Javascript on your web page is granted
// provided that all of the code (including this copyright notice) is
// used exactly as shown (you can change the numbering system if you wish)

// American Numbering System
var th = ['','thousand','million', 'billion','trillion'];
// uncomment this line for English Number System
// var th = ['','thousand','million', 'milliard','billion'];

var dg = ['zero','one','two','three','four', 'five','six','seven','eight','nine']; var tn = ['ten','eleven','twelve','thirteen', 'fourteen','fifteen','sixteen', 'seventeen','eighteen','nineteen']; var tw = ['twenty','thirty','forty','fifty', 'sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety']; function toWords(s){s = s.toString(); s = s.replace(/[\, ]/g,''); if (s != String(parseFloat(s))) return 'not a number'; var x = s.indexOf('.'); if (x == -1) x = s.length; if (x > 15) return 'too big'; var n = s.split(''); var str = ''; var sk = 0; for (var i=0; i < x; i++) {if ((x-i)%3==2) {if (n[i] == '1') {str += tn[Number(n[i+1])] + ' '; i++; sk=1;} else if (n[i]!=0) {str += tw[n[i]-2] + ' ';sk=1;}} else if (n[i]!=0) {str += dg[n[i]] +' '; if ((x-i)%3==0) str += 'hundred ';sk=1;} if ((x-i)%3==1) {if (sk) str += th[(x-i-1)/3] + ' ';sk=0;}} if (x != s.length) {var y = s.length; str += 'point '; for (var i=x+1; i<y; i++) str += dg[n[i]] +' ';} return str.replace(/\s+/g,' ');}
```